# How to traverse a list with up and down buttons?

Tags: android, button

I have implemented one "up" button and one "down" button in my layout.xml which I want to use in order to navigate through a ListView of strings. How can I accomplish this?
I do not want to use the "scroll" property of the ListView nor to use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation within a Scrollview in order to traverse the list. I simply want to move up and down my ListView by pressing the corresponding buttons.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a variable `int i = 0;` in your class body.
Then when the activity loads, the item at location 0 would be selected. If your user presses the down button, then do:

```
i++;
setSelection(i);
```

And similarly for going back up:

```
i--;
setSelection(i);
```

Of course you'd have to add logic to the code for when you're already at selection 0 or at the maximum selection, but that's the gist of how I'd do it.

To note, I've never used `ListView` as I've not needed to, but the above should work. I got all my information from [The Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int))

Comment: Thanks Jakar. This looks the appropriate way to go.